# Aurelia: Using Functions from Raphael.js, a legacy 3rd party library

Tags: raphael, legacy, aurelia

I am new to web development and therefore, Aurelia as well. I've been going through other questions and forums to try different ideas, but haven't found a solution. I think I may be missing something simple, but I'm not sure if my problem lies with how I'm adding the library, adding it into the module, bundling it, etc.

I am using Aurelia CLI and NPM.

In my test.js, I am trying to add the following, shown in the Raphael documentation:

```
let paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvasArea'), 100, 100);
let rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
```

My test.js is this:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as raphael from 'raphael';
@inject(raphael)
export class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.raphael = raphael;
        console.log(raphael);
    }
    attached() {
        this.createCan();
    }

    createCan() {
         let paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvasArea'), 100, 100);
         let rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

My test.html is this:

```
<template>
    <div id="canvasArea"></div>
</template>
```

My error, in the browser console, when loading the page is:

> Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined at Test.createCan...

The console log for raphael is an object.

```
Object
    > _ISURL: /^url\(['"]?(.+?)['"]?\)$/i
    > _Paper: ()
    > _availableAnimAttrs: Object
    > _availableAttrs: Object
    > ...
```

Some of the various ways I have tried without success are the following:

- not doing an inject
- import {raphael} from 'raphael'
- import raphael from 'raphael'
- do this.raphael.Raphael(...)
- do raphael.Raphael(...)
- using constructor(raphael) {...
- use a script on my index.html page instead
- prepend the raphael file in the aurelia.json file instead

To add Raphael.js, I did:

> npm install raphael --save

and added the following to my aurelia.json file:

```
"dependencies" : [
    {
        "name": "raphael",
        "path": "../node_modules/raphael",
        "main": "raphael.min",
        "deps": ["eve-raphael"]
    }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated such as possible solutions, better way to ask this question, where to look/what to read, other way to implement my end goal, etc. Thanks!

**Edits**
1. Clarification on location of error
2. Add some of console log for raphael

Comment: Have you also defined `eve-raphael` in your `dependencies` section of `aurelia-json`?  Since you've listed it as a dependency of `raphael`, you'll need to define it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add `Raphael.js` in the `prepend` section for the `vendor-bundle` in `aurelia.json`. I had tried this before, but I must have had other errors at that time too, such as `new Raphael(...)` instead of just `Raphael` (thanks @LStarky).

```
"prepend": [
    ...
    "node_modules/raphael/raphael.min.js",
    ...
]
```

While looking up what a legacy library was (thanks @LStarky), I got to the "A Very Stubborn Legacy Library" in the [Aurelia Documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6), which stated how sometimes libraries can't "work with the module loading system". My assumption is my problem falls under this category, especially since following this allowed me to use the 3rd party library.

Test.js now looks like this:

```
export class Test {
    constructor() {
    }
    attached() {
        this.createCan();
    }
    createCan() {
        let paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('canvasArea'), 100, 100);
        let rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can delete `constructor() {}` also... since it's not being used.  :-)  I'm glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've shared, and without any prior knowledge of raphael.js, your problem is maybe related to the dependency definitions in `aurelia.json`.  Since you've listed `eve-raphael` as a dependency of `raphael`, you'll need to also add `eve-raphael` to your `aurelia.json` file.

Or, you could try deleting the `deps` line from `aurelia.json` (and the preceding comma), to see whether it really requires that dependency.

If this is not the solution, could you please copy/paste the specific errors you're getting when you run `au run --watch`?

**Edit:**

If this is a legacy 3rd party library, you also can most likely delete the Aurelia-specific instantiation in `Test.js`, like this:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'raphael';
export class Test {
    constructor() {
    }
    attached() {
        this.createCan();
    }

    createCan() {
         let paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('canvasArea'), 100, 100);
         let rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not list `eve-raphael` in the `aurelia.json` file. I will add that, although I don't think that is my problem, currently anyway. I don't have any errors when I do `au run --watch`. My error shows up in the browser console

Comment: I just edited my response, given that you're not getting errors in `aurelia.json`.  You don't need to inject a legacy class, just import it.  But check the case.

Comment: I couldn't find a clarification on what a legacy 3rd party library would be. What is it?
I still get an error in the browser console. This time as `Raphael is not a constructor`

Comment: After checking the library definition, I edited my response again.  Delete `new` since it's not a constructor.  It's just a function.  Definitely use the simple import `import 'raphael';`.  See above code.

Comment: Error is `Raphael is not defined`. Maybe there's a problem with how the library was added or bundled?

Comment: This might be worth noting: it doesn't say `Tracing raphael` when I include `import 'raphael'` in `test.js`, but it does when I comment out all the lines pertaining to raphael

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to help but this looks like it's out of my area of expertise.

Comment: I found the solution, which I've posted. However, I wouldn't have gotten there without your help, particularly with not using `new` and saying `legacy` which I used as keyword to find my solution. Thanks!